# How can I format a USB/SD card that I'm not able to format with the dd command?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, format, dd, fat32

I have this 32Gb micro SD card that was on my android phone. It was working as an external HD.

Now I want to format the SD card to use with another phone, but it seems impossible to format.

I've tried to format without success:

- with the old phone
- with the new phone
- with gparted
- with disks
- with dd command
- manually deleting items with `shift+delete`
- with windows (because..who knows)

None of this worked. I still have all the files in the SD.

**Errors**

*Gparted:*

I see an orange triangle with the exclamation mark:

```
Fat problem while decoding 2 0
Streamcache allocation problem:: 2
Fat problem while decoding 2 0
Streamcache allocation problem:: 2
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for fat32 file system support:  dosfstools, mtools.
```

I have dosfstools and mtools installed.

*dd command:*

Used the commands

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512 count=16`

and then

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M`

the result were a bunch of similar errors:

```
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992321] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992331] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992337] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Peripheral device write fault
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992344] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 01 05 28 00 00 f0 00
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992348] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 66856
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992355] buffer_io_error: 230 callbacks suppressed
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992360] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64808, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992368] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64809, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992371] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64810, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992394] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64811, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992397] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64812, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992401] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64813, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992405] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64814, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992408] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64815, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992419] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64816, lost async page write
Jan 10 00:30:41 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34628.992423] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 64817, lost async page write
```

with the last one

```
Jan 10 00:31:36 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34683.849080] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan 10 00:31:36 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34683.849160] scsi host14: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.847904] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.848611] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.961392] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] 61405184 512-byte logical blocks: (31.4 GB/29.2 GiB)
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.961692] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.961698] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.961971] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.961978] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.964368]  sdb: sdb1
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34684.965321] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jan 10 00:31:37 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34685.137339] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853595] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853606] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853611] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Peripheral device write fault
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853617] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 08 01 00 00 01 00
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853622] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2049
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853628] buffer_io_error: 470 callbacks suppressed
Jan 10 00:32:33 asus-ux305fa kernel: [34740.853633] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1, lost async page write
```

Why I can't format this SD card?

edit: correct typo in the first command

@roboboykm:

It is a micro SD with no lock. Following the instruction in your comment here the results:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 31.4 GB, 31439454208 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3807 cylinders, total 61405184 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    61405183    30701568    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

I've tried partprobe but it is not working either. Rebooting the system doesn't help too.

Answer (score 1):

You used:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=//dev/sdb1 bs=512 count=16
```

But you should have used:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=16
```

Using `sdb1` in the first instance processes the first partition.

Using `sdb` in the second instance processes the first sector containing the `MBR` and the partition table. After the partition table is zeroed then `gparted` can be used to create new partitions.

On a side note if you are interested in a wrapper script that ensures you never run dd on your `sda` by accident see this ([Prevent `dd` from destroying SSD or HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867746/how-can-i-automatically-prevent-dd-from-destroying-my-ssd-and-hdd)) script I wrote last week.

Comment: That's correct, I found also a typo in the command. However I did the command with `sdb` but it is not working at all. It's like for some reason nothing can write on the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that sd card switch is at unlocked position

you can use fdisk command

```
 sudo fdisk /dev/sdx

   Type the following parameters (each followed by <ENTER>):

   **p**  [lists the current partitions]

   **d**  [to delete existing partitions. Repeat this until no unnecessary    partitions are reported by the 'p' command to start fresh.]

   **p** [to check if any partition left]

   **n**   [create a new partition]

   **p**   [create a primary partition - use for both partitions][create a primary partition - use for both partitions]

   **1**   [the first partition]

   **20480**  [starting at offset sector]

    <Press Enter key > [using the default value will create a partition that extends to the last sector of the media]

 **p** to check the partition

   **w**   [write]


 sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdx1
```

Where x can be replaced by device you get like sdc or sdb

Comment: I've added the results in the main question

Comment: @Alessio try the edited steps

Comment: @Alessio use sudo before fdisk command or work as root , also find in /dev/ what partition name has come like sdx1

Comment: there is a typo in the **20480** should be only **2048**. I followed your instructions, and this message came out `WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.`

As I mentioned above, I did alredy a test with partprobe with no results.