# Not able to do any changes to bootable usb

Tags: boot, usb

I tried creating a bootable usb using my 32GB pendrive. It was not completed successfully. After that there is just a file in it called "~MSSETUP.T". I cant copy any files to it, cant format it, cant do anything to it even with superuser access.I have tried using gparted, disks, mkusb ,mkfs, wipefs,dosfsck and cfdisk. All these tools show that the action was successful but after refreshing it again comes back to the same condition. There is only one fat32 partition labelled with lba,boot and I cant resize it, delete it or change anything of it. I also tried using diskpart on windows but it does not work.
Please help
Thank You

Comment: Have you tried format it using `dd` tools ?

Comment: I suggest that you analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035). If you are lucky there is a problem, that can be solved. Good luck :-)

Comment: yes I have tried them. They dont work.

Comment: Did you try to erase the USB with `dd` first?: [How can I format a USB/SD card that I'm not able to format with the dd command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870141/how-can-i-format-a-usb-sd-card-that-im-not-able-to-format-with-the-dd-command/870194#870194)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usb is probably corrupt to a point where you can't use it anymore so I would recommend using a different usb drive