# Can't install ubuntu alongside windows on dell xps 13

Tags: usb-installation

It fail each time after I choose the wifi, ubi partman code 141 or 10, some time it says that I have 0 gb of storage available, once I was able to click on install alongsde windows but it failed just after, sometime it says this machine's firmware has started the installer in uefi mode.

In bios I've disabled raid on, secure boot, I've enabled uefi stack option.
Thanks you

Comment: did you make free space on the HDD for the install?

Comment: Yes I've shrinked 20 gb in disk utility

Comment: Dual booting with Windows 10? If so did you turn Windows fast start up off? If you disabled RAID, did you set to AHCI? Some with Dell have said to have Legacy boot on, but still boot in UEFI. Almost everyone else has to have UEFI on and Legacy off, or else system will be in BIOS/Legacy mode. And selecting UEFI mode to boot flash drive installer is still required. see also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353288 and: https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN

Comment: @WilliamP -- 20GB might be enough to install but leaves very little room to do anything else. I would make at least 50GB freespace

Comment: @oldfred I've turned fast start up off, set ahci, legacy off how can I select uefi mode to boot flash drive installer ?

Comment: if legacy is off, then EFI is guaranteed since it is the only boot mode left. it is only when legacy is enabled that you have to worry about how it booted

Comment: @ravery so what should I do more ? i've tried installing it a lot's of time, what do I do wrong ?

Comment: did yu read the links that oldfred posted?

Comment: Yes, I've donne the same the first time I've tried. Is there a way to rest all setting without loosing my windows 10 configuration and try It again ?

Comment: Just tried it again, After I click on connect to wifi, I can't continue and I'm stuck here.

Comment: I thought Dell needed Legacy on, but you still can and must choose UEFI to boot installer & after install. Some system need wi-fi drivers that are not in the installer, so best to install using Ethernet hard wired and then update system. if still issues then another question on Wireless required. When booting from a flash drive your UEFI will  offer two boot options UEFI:flash or flash where flash is name or label of flash drive. Use the UEFI:flash only. Or create a UEFI only bootable installer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: I've made a bit of progress, I went to the page were you have to choose install alongside windows but this option is not here, I've tried other and it didn't show me the partitions, and I was stuck there. Also, windows boot manager disapeared in the bios order.

Comment: @oldfred when I launch try ubuntu I cannot do anything I can't enter terminal and can't satr gparted

Comment: Now I have this : Installer crashed we're sorry the installer crashed. After you close this window...

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI from Dell and if NVMe drive latest firmware? Have you verified installer is correct? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM Have you used Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and rebooted so it can run chkdsk which is required after every NTFS resize?  Have you tried to create partitions with gparted and then use Something Else to choose (change button) partition as / (root)? https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I hate to contradict @ravery but I've been using 30GB for Ubuntu with LibreOffice, FireFox, Chrome and usual utilities on space limited 128GB mSata SSD. The only time I ran out of space is when I did a full system backup to compressed `.tar.gz` without deleting the previous full backup.

Comment: @oldfred After reading OP's answer I wonder if we should Vote To Close as a hardware problem?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix -- Sure, I currently use 7GB in / and 11GB in home, but I also have a 200B data on another partition.

Comment: I typically create a 25GB or so / (root) partition and my 16.04 is using about 9GB, but all data normally in /home is in /mnt/data including some of the larger hidden folders with data. I have seen many threads where users tried a different flash drive, different installer or different port and then it worked. Never could tell if change solved problem or if just not done correctly first time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me, the problem came from the usb key, Don't use sandisk's UltraFit key. It worked with a shitty made one that I grabed for free.

Comment: On my Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE I found out I couldn't [install from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870452/iso-linux-6-03-error-booting-live-usb) when other USB devices were plugged in, probably most especially an Android cell phone.