# Linux Error Reporting Removable Disk Size

Tags: drive, parted, gdisk

I recently had a strange error while trying to partition removable usb drives.  lsblk correctly reported the drive configuration. However when I tried to dd an image to the drive dd error'd, reporting the (8GB) drive as being just 2GB. gdisk reported the same result, as did KDE partitionmanager. However, I could write zeros to the drive partitions, eg /dev/sdb1. 
I tried another drive with exactly the same result.
I ran partprobe which had no result. 
I also received an error at some point stating that /dev/disk/by-label/sdb did not exist. 
I rebooted and the error disappeared, so no harm. I was wondering if anybody knows what might have happened, and how to recover from the error without rebooting?.

Comment: what is the format of the USB is it Fat or Fat32 .. If I remember correctly Fat only will handle up to 2GB  check the format and if its just FAT then format it as FAT32

Answer (score 0):

- Often the kernel {is not/cannot be} updated, when the partition table of a drive is modified.
- Sometimes it helps to run

  ```
  sudo partprobe
  ```

  (to fix such issues without rebooting).
- I too have noticed that `lsblk` is often better than other tools to report the correct data about drives.
- As you noticed already, rebooting is a good method to get the data about partition tables correct.

  But sometimes it is a good idea to avoid rebooting, as illustrated by the following link,

  [Accidentally did dd /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda/982595#982595)