# beleive it or not, I typed sudo rm -r * in / by mistake! anyway to undo

Tags: rm

lol is there anything more to ask about it?!
when I try "sudo bla bla bla" it asks me who are you?
:)) I wanted to do it IN a folder in root, but I did it in only ne upper level which is, GOD, the root folder!

Comment: You nuked it. No easy way to un-nuke it. Time to reinstall.  One hopes you learned the lesson about `rm`, wildcards, and haste.

Comment: Did you remove the system root `/` (very bad) or 'only' the directory `/root` (not that bad)?

Comment: @sudodus the option "very bad" is correct :|
the adress is "/"

Comment: I recommend using Clonezilla. By making image backups to another drive, you can reverse mistakes.

Comment: Clonezilla will skip unused space (and the data of the deleted files are considered unused). So it cannot be used to recover the removed data in this case. But in the future Clonezilla can provide an alternative to create complete images for backup and recovery (from a backup image) of the whole system.

Answer (score 2):

The highest priority should be to save the content of your [most important] personal files. For this purpose I think you should **avoid writing anything** to your drive.

My way to do it is to shutdown the computer and reboot from another drive (typically an Ubuntu live drive or a linux rescue system), and if you have valuable data in the drive, to clone it with **`ddrescue`** to a third drive, and after that do recovery work on the cloned copy. This way you can afford mistakes (and in that case clone the drive again and try again to recover data from the cloned copy). The tools Testdisk and PhotoRec from http://cgsecurity.org might be useful.

This is described in some details in the following links,

- [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) - scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files',
- [Accidentally did dd /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda/982649#982649) - Not exactly your problem, but the method might work for you too.