# Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver install hangs after choosing keyboard layout

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, keyboard-layout, freeze

No matter if I choose "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" on boot from USB, always when I have chosen a keyboard layout the "Ubuntu Installer" hangs with the mouse courser spinning tirelessly.

I can run "Ubuntu Install" in live Ubuntu so I should be able to do some configurations or something, but I have no clue where to look.

Comment: Try [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info). That's the easy way. If it doesn't work comment and then we'll move on to plan B, the hard way.

Comment: Well the easy way didn't work, so I'm guessing the hard way is the way to go. 
I followed this "https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu" to set the nomodeset flag.

Comment: [Can't boot from Ubuntu USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018918/cant-boot-from-ubuntu-usb-stick/1020785#1020785)

Comment: Yup, it did the trick.

Comment: Actually this is a workaround, not a duplicate of that bug. I can boot into and run the Installer but it hangs after choosing keyboard layout.