# Can I download a version of Ubuntu on to a disc?

Tags: 16.04

I would like to download the appropriate version of Ubuntu onto a cdrom so that I can install it into a computer with no functioning operating system. Can that be done?

Comment: It won't fit on a CD. These days most people use USB thumb drive.

Comment: We have no idea of what computer, what architecture (ie. what cpu is installed, if it's amd64 (or x86-64), i386 (or x86), armh etc) or what you want to use it for (desktop, server etc).  Yes you can.  You tagged 16.04 which means the 2016-April release of Ubuntu because releases use a *year.month* format to show release; meaning 18.04 is two years newer.

Comment: Some doco - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-ubuntu-desktop/13618/2
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-ubuntu-server/13949 https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-windows/14008
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-macos/14015 https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-verify-your-ubuntu-download/14010 etc

Comment: The minimal install is 40Mb but newer are likely to be around 60Mb. Fits on a CD. You then could set up an internet connection and pull the remaining software from the web. Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot from Ubuntu USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018918/cant-boot-from-ubuntu-usb-stick)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Go to https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop to download the latest desktop version of Ubuntu

It will download an ISO file. You can burn the file onto a blank CD using. Here is a link to a tutorial on how to [burn an ISO file onto a disk](https://www.wikihow.com/Burn-ISO-Files-to-DVD).

Comment: From the link "Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media" ;-)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD had the CD installers.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could be a contributing part of this community but I am quite ill and I also know next to nothing about computers and technology in general. I am old. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the ISO from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop insert a blank disc into your drive.  Burn the disc using **Startup Disk Creator**.