# Simulate a USB stick insert

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I inserted a USB stick on my laptop and it automount the partition.
I then did a umount /dev/sdb* to allow me to DD an image to it.
Once DD is done, I do sync then physically unplug the USB then plug it back to get the 2 partitions mounted.

my question is how can I avoid to physically unplug the USB and plug it back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unmount

You can unmount all partitions without trying to unmount the device itself with

```
sudo umount /dev/sdx?*
```

Replace the device letter **`x`** with the relevant device letter, for example **`b`**

### Clone

It is a good idea to use a cloning tool with a final checkpoint,

[Accidentally did dd /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda/982649#982649)

Scroll down to 'Safer tools to create USB boot drives with Ubuntu'

- In Ubuntu you can use **'Disks'** alias gnome-disks or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- In Windows you can use [Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD)

### Sync, Partprobe, Mount

```
sync
sudo partprobe
```

Try mounting after creating the new system on the USB stick

This command line should work with one or more partitions,

```
for i in $(lsblk -l -o name|grep -E "sdx.{1,}");do sudo mkdir -p /media/$USER/"$i";sudo mount /dev/"$i" /media/$USER/"$i";done
```

Replace the device letter **`x`** with the relevant device letter, for example **`b`**

Comment: what's the advantage to do sudo umount /dev/sdx?* versus sudo umount /dev/sdx*

Comment: disk cloning, I prefer to keep my system simple. dd is already installed but thanks for the heads up

Comment: big thanks for the command to re mount the drive works perfectly!

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeDescamps, I'm glad it works for you :-) The advantage with ?* is that the system does not try (and fail) to unmount the drive itself (`/dev/sdx`), but only tries to unmount the partitions `/dev/sdx1`, `/dev/sdx2`, ... The questionmark makes it look for one wild card character and the asterisk makes it look for any number of characters (zero or more).

Answer (score 1):

If remember correctly you need to run one command after `sync`:

```
sudo partprobe
```

From its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/partprobe.8.html):

> NAME
>      partprobe - inform the OS of partition table changes
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      partprobe is a program that informs the operating system kernel of par-
>      tition table changes.

Comment: +1. I am using partprobe in some of my scripts for mkusb, and it does its job well with USB sticks. But I think you still have to unplug memory cards.

Comment: i tried but didnt work
i did
lsblk and i can see the mount points
sudo umount /dev/sdb*
lsblk and i can NOT see the mount points
sudo partprobe
lsblk and i can still NOT see the mount points