# How to restore data part by part after dd?

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss

I wiped out data on external HDD (NTFS) by dd. Wanted to write ISO on usb-stick. But I don't have any storage that could embrace volume of those external HDD. So I need to safe part of data here and part there during recovery (Testdisk tells that there not enough space).

Could you recommend software ? And would be nice to have guidance through this.

Comment: 1. Did you shutdown or reboot the computer yet? I ask because relevant data for recovery may still reside in RAM. See the accepted answer to this question, [Accidentally did dd /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda/); 2. In order to succeed, you may need a target drive of at least the same size as the damaged (overwritten) source drive.

Comment: @sudodus I think I didn't shutdown, do I need the same size anyway ?

Comment: I did not write that answer, and I have not [yet] been in a situation to use it. Please read it very carefully and ask afterwards, if necessary, in a way to make other people respond. I am not sure, but it is a very good idea to have a cloned copy of the drive, particularly if there are valuable data.

Comment: “I don't have any storage that could embrace volume of those external HDD” OK then go buy one and get back to us after that, although we cannot really recommend specific shops or brands.