# Possible to rescue SSD that doesn't show any partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, disk, gdisk

I had a laptop SSD suffer water damage. The rest of the laptop appears to work fine, however the SSD, a Kingston SNS8152S3256GG2,  seems to have completely failed and the OS won't boot at all, so I am using a GParted live disk and connecting the SSD with a M.2 to USB device. `gparted` and `fdisk -l` do not show the device `/dev/sda`. `gdisk /dev/sda` has this output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

Output of `i`: `No partitions`

Output of `p`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 0 sectors, 0 bytes
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2E1AE37A-8EDD-4014-A35B-F7AAD7556C29
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 18446744073709551582
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Output of `v`:

```
Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data!
(Disk size is 0 sectors, needs to be 0 sectors.)
The 'e' option on the experts' menu may fix this problem.

Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 18446744073709551582, but backup header is at
18446744073709551615 and disk size is 0 sectors.
The 'e' option on the experts' menu will probably fix this problem

Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.

Identified 3 problems!
```

I highly doubt I'll be able to recover anything from the disk (which contained a Windows partition and an Ubuntu partition) but any suggestions for what to do from here? Should I create a new GPT or just accept the disk is gone? Is it possible to get `/dev/sda` readable so I can try ddrescue or photorec?

Comment: Are there any files on the SSD, that are not backed up to other media, and that you want to recover? Or are you 'only' trying to rescue the SSD drive?

Comment: @sudodus I'm trying to recover the files but I'm not hopeful

Comment: In order to recover the files, you must 'see' the SSD as a mass storage device `/dev/sdx` where x is the drive letter a or b or c ... If you do, you can try to **clone** the drive with `ddrescue` to another (new) drive with at least the same size, and then do the recovery work on the cloned copy. See this link and links from it, [Recover the partition table, file systems and/or file content](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda/982649#982649)