# Trying to use extundelete for recovering a "rm -rf"ed directory. But receiving this: extundelete: No such file or directory /dev/sda5

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery, rm, umount

so I accidentally deleted a dirrectory using "rm -rf". I am trying to recover is using extundelete.
So far I have done these:

> $ sudo umount -l /dev/sda5
> $ extundelete --restore-directory {directory_path} /dev/sda5

When I enter the last command it says:

> extundelete: No such file or directory  /dev/sda5
> extundelete: No such file or directory when trying to open filesystem /dev/sda5

Any idea why?

Comment: `umount` needs root privileges normally. Are you sure the device name is correct? Please provide output of `lsblk`.

Comment: did you run `umount` and `extundelete` as `root` or using `sudo` ?

Comment: You can also explore using the related tools [TestDisk and PhotoRec](https://cgsecurity.org).

Comment: I did with "sudo umount" but after that sudo did not work. thus I only did "extundelete"

Comment: Answers in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda) may help, particularly if you do not turn off the computer. Otherwise there is a risk, that things are lost; maybe you can save some of the removed files using the data that is still there on the drive. Anyway, *if* you turn off the computer, boot from a live drive and avoid mounting the affected drive.